# Export Swing Component to PDF using iText

Tags: java, swing, pdf, itext

I have a frame and there are several components on it. How do I paint this JFrame using iText?

I write some code as follow(but does not work):

```
public void PrintFrameToPDF(Component c, File file) {
    try {
        Document d = new Document();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(d, new FileOutputStream(file));
        d.open();

        PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
        PdfTemplate template = cb.createTemplate(c.getWidth(), c.getHeight());
        Graphics2D g2d = template.createGraphics(c.getWidth(), c.getHeight());
        c.paintAll(g2d);
        c.addNotify();
        c.validate();
        g2d.dispose();

        d.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "does not work" mean?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25579480/how-to-export-jpanel-with-scrollable-into-pdf-file Brother, Please Look upon this solution,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First createTemplate uses its own units:

```
createTemplate(PageSize.A4.getHeight(), PageSize.A4.getWidth());
```

You could use:

```
g2d.translate(48.0, 48.0);
```

And delete addNotify and validate. Especially as you called getHeight, validate makes no sense. After g2d.dispose do:

```
cb.addTemplate(template, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Joop Eggen - Waht you mean by g2d.translate(48.0, 48.0) For me noew Pdf is ahving some Frame content, but not fully visible.

Comment: The g2d.translate shoves the content a bit up and right, for the margins. You have to see for yourself, sorry.

Comment: Or any Other way to Capture JFrame and Fit into PDf

Comment: Using Graphics2D `transform` and `scale` already is a hack. There should be better ways in itext. Sorry.