# How can I save a Prefuse generated graph as a pdf in java?

Tags: graph, save, social-networking, graph-visualization, prefuse

I am using Prefuse java API in my java code to visualize a network. I was wondering, how can I save the image? I want to save it as a pdf? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

prefuse draws the graph visualization in a `Display`, which is a subclass of `JComponent`.

Thus you can apply tutorials to save Swing components on PDF:

- [Export Swing Component to PDF using iText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8731462/export-swing-component-to-pdf-using-itext)
- http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2006/jw-1209-swing.html