# How to save a JEditorPane as a pdf?

Tags: java, swing, pdf

I'm trying to save text from a JEditorPane as a pdf once a save button is clicked.

```
saveAs.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            String title = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a name for file...");
            try{
                paintToPDF(newBlanktoEdit, title);
            }catch (Exception exc){
                exc.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

The method `paintToPDF` does the job correctly, however the `Pane` is parsed as a `graphics2D` component, and so wrapping the line is not possible.

```
protected void paintToPDF(JEditorPane newPane, String title) throws Exception{

    newPane.setBounds(0, 0, (int) convertToPixels(612 - 58), (int) convertToPixels(792 - 60));

    Document doc = new Document();
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(title + ".pdf");
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, out);

    doc.setPageSize(new com.lowagie.text.Rectangle(612, 792));
    doc.open();
    PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
    cb.saveState();
    cb.concatCTM(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);

    DefaultFontMapper mapper = new DefaultFontMapper();
    mapper.insertDirectory("c:/windows/fonts");

    Graphics2D g = cb.createGraphics(612, 792, mapper, true, .92f);

    AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
    at.translate(convertToPixels(20), convertToPixels(20));
    at.scale(pixelToPoint, pixelToPoint);

    g.transform(at);
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fill(newPane.getBounds());

    Rectangle alloc = getVisivleEditorRect(newPane);
    newPane.getUI().getRootView(newPane).paint(g, alloc);

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.draw(newPane.getBounds());

    g.dispose();
    cb.restoreState();
    doc.close();
    out.flush();
    out.close();
}

private float convertToPixels(int points){

    return (float) (points / pixelToPoint);
}

private Rectangle getVisivleEditorRect(JEditorPane newPane){

    Rectangle alloc = newPane.getBounds();
    if((alloc.width > 0) && (alloc.height > 0)){
        alloc.x = alloc.y = 0;
        Insets insets = newPane.getInsets();
        alloc.x += insets.left;
        alloc.y += insets.top;
        alloc.width -= insets.left + insets.right;
        alloc.height -= insets.top + insets.bottom;
        return alloc;
    }
    return null;
}
```

with,

```
int inch = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenResolution();
float pixelToPoint = (float) 72 / (float) inch;
```

I'm looking for a solution based on an external library, i tried expermenting with iText and PDFBox, to no avail so far.

I want to point out that the solution above uses `com.lowagie`library.

Comment: You want to save the form of the editor pane or the text in it?

Comment: The text, and just to clarity, the JEditorPane can be changed to a JtextPane, or JTextArea, depending on the solution you have in mind.

Comment: You could use StandardPrint first to turn your JEditorPane (or other Component) display into an Image, and then convert that into a PDF using lowagie: https://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/print/StandardPrint.java

Comment: Can you make an example on how it should look like? With iText it's not difficult to do it. `com.lowagie` refers to `iText` actually, just in the first releases they did, later the package was changed to `itext`

Comment: i have no preferences on how it should look like, as long as it's saved as a pdf file, nothing special. Can you show how it would be done using iText ?, and thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you want to convert your GUI to images and print it in a PDF, if this is not what you want please clarify.

Here's a simple program that creates the following GUI (without the text written in it), which is a `JTextArea` and a `JButton`.

[image]

When clicked, the button opens a new Document, takes the area and converts it to an image, then adds that image to the PDF and later does the same with the button, so you get a similar output in a PDF like this one:

[image]

The trick is to use both `java.awt.Image` and `com.itextpdf.text.Image`, the former to convert the `JComponent` to images and the latter to print them in the PDF, this trick was found and based on this peeskillet's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25580014/2180785).

So, without further explanation, here's the code that achieves the results above:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Image;
import com.itextpdf.text.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class PdfFromUserInput {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextArea area;
    private JButton button;
    private Document document;
    private PdfWriter writer;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new PdfFromUserInput().createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }

    public void openPdf() throws FileNotFoundException, DocumentException {
        document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 30, 30, 30, 30);
        writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("myFile.pdf"));
        document.open();
    }

    public void closePdf() {
        document.close();
    }

    public java.awt.Image getImageFromComponent(JComponent component) throws DocumentException {
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(component.getWidth(), component.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        component.paint(image.getGraphics());
        return image;
    }

    public void addImageToDocument(java.awt.Image img) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        Image image = Image.getInstance(writer, img, 1);
        image.scalePercent(50);
        document.add(image);
        System.out.println("printed!");
    }

    public void createAndShowGui() {
        frame = new JFrame("PDF creator");
        area = new JTextArea(10, 30);
        area.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
        button = new JButton("Create PDF");

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    openPdf();
                    java.awt.Image img = getImageFromComponent(area);
                    addImageToDocument(img);
                    img = getImageFromComponent(button);
                    addImageToDocument(img);
                    closePdf();
                } catch (DocumentException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        frame.add(area, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```