# Convert to image of a JTable within a JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

I have a `JTable` inside a `JScrollPane`, which is under a `JPanel`. I need to export the table as an image. It works fine if the table is small enough to be viewed completely in the `JScrollPane`, without the scrollbar. But if the table is too big and needs scroller to go right and left or up and down, then only part of the table is visible in the exported image. 
I am using the following code

```
public BufferedImage componentToImage( Component component, boolean visible)
{
    if (visible)
    {
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(component.getWidth(), component.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TRANSLUCENT);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) img.getGraphics();
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        component.paintAll(g2d);
        try
        {
            File outputfile = new File("C:\\Users\\SciOme Admin\\Desktop\\a.png");
            ImageIO.write(img, "png", outputfile);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return img;
    }
}
```

where I am passing `JScrollPane` as the component.
I am getting attached partial image, with scroll bars. But I need the complete `JTable`.

[image]

I can't pass the `JTable` as the component, as I am using two overlapping tables in the `JScrollPane`. One table is used to just show the row headers and keep them visible always, even when scrolling to the right.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42534763/how-to-save-a-jtable-on-pdf-with-a-jtable-header/42538618#42538618) could help you...

Comment: Try to pass `JTable` to `componentToImage`

Comment: @c0der Because they seem to be using the row header support of the `JScrollPane`, that won't work

Comment: You'll need to devise a solution which allows you to paint both the scroll pane's row header, column header AND the `JTable` side by side.  This is no easy task to say the least.  You're probably going to have to resort to some fancy trickery to make it work, extracting the column model and renderer, the row header, set up the `JTable` so the column widths are correct and then manually paint each of the to the image

Comment: @MadProgrammer would it be easier to disable row header support, pass `JTable` to `componentToImage` and enable row header support again ?

Comment: @c0der I think is generally the problem the OP is having.  `JTable` delegates the column and row header to the `JScrollPane`, so they aren't rendered as part of the `JTable`. Assuming the OP wants the table to be saved as it's displayed, then they will need to also paint the row and column header themselves

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on you image, I would suggest that you are making use of the `JScrollPane`'s `rowHeader` support.  Rendering a `JTable` is not an easy task at the best of times, normally you'd just make use of the table's inbuilt support for printing, but that doesn't take into account the `JScrollPane`s `rowHeader`, and a large enough table might want to print to multiple pages, and that just gets messy.

In your case, you're going to have to disassemble the `JScrollPane` and render the `rowHeader`, `columnHeader` and main `view` yourself.

At a "very" basic level, this would invoke calculating the overall size required to render all the components, calculating the offset positions for each component and painting them, something like this...

```
Component columnHeader = scrollPane.getColumnHeader().getView();
Component rowHeader = scrollPane.getRowHeader().getView();
Component view = scrollPane.getViewport().getView();

int width = rowHeader.getPreferredSize().width + view.getPreferredSize().width;
int height = columnHeader.getPreferredSize().height + view.getPreferredSize().height;

BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
g2d.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
int xOffset = rowHeader.getPreferredSize().width;
int yOffset = columnHeader.getPreferredSize().height;

Graphics2D rowHeaderG = (Graphics2D) g2d.create();
rowHeaderG.translate(0, yOffset);
rowHeader.printAll(rowHeaderG);
rowHeaderG.dispose();

Graphics2D colHeaderG = (Graphics2D) g2d.create();
colHeaderG.translate(xOffset, 0);
columnHeader.printAll(colHeaderG);
colHeaderG.dispose();

Graphics2D viewG = (Graphics2D) g2d.create();
viewG.translate(xOffset, yOffset);
view.printAll(viewG);
viewG.dispose();
g2d.dispose();
```

I borrowed some code from an older example and implemented the basic idea as an example.  Since I don't have your code, any additional issues you have you're going to have to try and solve yourself (it's hard to debug by crystal ball), but this should give you helping start

From the window...

[image: From the frame]

to the image...

[image: to the image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JViewport;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.event.TableColumnModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TableColumnModelListener;
import javax.swing.table.JTableHeader;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;

public class TableRowHeaderTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TableRowHeaderTest();
    }

    public TableRowHeaderTest() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                Object rowData1[][]
                        = {
                            {"", "", "", ""},
                            {"", "", "", ""},
                            {"", "", "", ""},
                            {"", "", "", ""}
                        };

                Object columnNames1[] = {"HEADER 1", "HEADER 2", "HEADER 3", "HEADER 4"};

                JTable table1 = new TableWithRowHeader(rowData1, columnNames1);

                table1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(120);

                JScrollPane scrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(table1);
//                scrollPane1.setColumnHeaderView(null);

                JButton print = new JButton("Save");
                print.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        print(scrollPane1);
                    }
                });

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(scrollPane1);
                frame.add(print, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    protected void print(JScrollPane scrollPane) {
        Component columnHeader = scrollPane.getColumnHeader().getView();
        Component rowHeader = scrollPane.getRowHeader().getView();
        Component view = scrollPane.getViewport().getView();

        int width = rowHeader.getPreferredSize().width + view.getPreferredSize().width;
        int height = columnHeader.getPreferredSize().height + view.getPreferredSize().height;

        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
        g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
        int xOffset = rowHeader.getPreferredSize().width;
        int yOffset = columnHeader.getPreferredSize().height;

        Graphics2D rowHeaderG = (Graphics2D) g2d.create();
        rowHeaderG.translate(0, yOffset);
        rowHeader.printAll(rowHeaderG);
        rowHeaderG.dispose();

        Graphics2D colHeaderG = (Graphics2D) g2d.create();
        colHeaderG.translate(xOffset, 0);
        columnHeader.printAll(colHeaderG);
        colHeaderG.dispose();

        Graphics2D viewG = (Graphics2D) g2d.create();
        viewG.translate(xOffset, yOffset);
        view.printAll(viewG);
        viewG.dispose();
        g2d.dispose();

        try {
            ImageIO.write(img, "png", new File("Test.png"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public class TableWithRowHeader extends JTable {

        private TableRowHeader rowHeader;

        public TableWithRowHeader(final Object[][] rowData, final Object[] columnNames) {
            super(rowData, columnNames);
            rowHeader = new TableRowHeader(this);
            setGridColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        }

        @Override
        protected void configureEnclosingScrollPane() {
            // This is required as it calls a private method...
            super.configureEnclosingScrollPane();

            Container parent = SwingUtilities.getUnwrappedParent(this);
            if (parent instanceof JViewport) {

                JViewport port = (JViewport) parent;
                Container gp = port.getParent();
                if (gp instanceof JScrollPane) {

                    JScrollPane scrollPane = (JScrollPane) gp;
                    JViewport viewport = scrollPane.getViewport();
                    if (viewport == null || SwingUtilities.getUnwrappedView(viewport) != this) {
                        return;
                    }
//                    scrollPane.setColumnHeaderView(null);
                    scrollPane.setRowHeaderView(rowHeader);
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public class TableRowHeader extends JTableHeader {

        private JTable table;

        public TableRowHeader(JTable table) {
            super(table.getColumnModel());
            this.table = table;

            table.getColumnModel().addColumnModelListener(new TableColumnModelListener() {

                @Override
                public void columnAdded(TableColumnModelEvent e) {
                    repaint();
                }

                @Override
                public void columnRemoved(TableColumnModelEvent e) {
                    repaint();
                }

                @Override
                public void columnMoved(TableColumnModelEvent e) {
                    repaint();
                }

                @Override
                public void columnMarginChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                    repaint();
                }

                @Override
                public void columnSelectionChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                    // Don't care about this, want to highlight the row...
                }
            });
            table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
                @Override
                public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                    repaint();
                }
            });
        }

        public JTable getTable() {
            return table;
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            Dimension size = new Dimension();
            JTable table = getTable();
            if (table != null) {
                TableColumnModel model = table.getColumnModel();
                if (model != null) {

                    for (int index = 0; index < model.getColumnCount(); index++) {

                        TableColumn column = model.getColumn(index);
                        TableCellRenderer renderer = column.getHeaderRenderer();
                        if (renderer == null) {

                            renderer = getDefaultRenderer();

                        }
                        Component comp = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, column.getHeaderValue(), false, false, -1, index);
                        size.width = Math.max(comp.getPreferredSize().width, size.width);
                        size.height += table.getRowHeight(index);

                    }

                }
            }
            return size;

        }

        /**
         * Overridden to avoid propagating a invalidate up the tree when the
         * cell renderer child is configured.
         */
        @Override
        public void invalidate() {
        }

        /**
         * If the specified component is already a child of this then we don't
         * bother doing anything - stacking order doesn't matter for cell
         * renderer components (CellRendererPane doesn't paint anyway).
         */
        @Override
        protected void addImpl(Component x, Object constraints, int index) {
            if (x.getParent() == this) {
                return;
            } else {
                super.addImpl(x, constraints, index);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

//            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

            g2d.setColor(getBackground());
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

            JTable table = getTable();
            if (table != null) {

                int width = getWidth();

                TableColumnModel model = table.getColumnModel();
                if (model != null) {

                    for (int index = 0; index < model.getColumnCount(); index++) {

                        TableColumn column = model.getColumn(index);
                        TableCellRenderer renderer = column.getHeaderRenderer();
                        if (renderer == null) {

                            renderer = getDefaultRenderer();

                        }

                        boolean selected = table.getSelectedRow() == index;

                        Component comp = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, column.getHeaderValue(), selected, false, 0, index);

                        add(comp);
                        comp.validate();

                        int height = table.getRowHeight(index) - 1;
                        comp.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
                        comp.paint(g2d);
                        comp.setBounds(-width, -height, 0, 0);

                        g2d.setColor(table.getGridColor());
                        g2d.drawLine(0, height, width, height);

                        g2d.translate(0, height + 1);

                    }

                }
            }
            g2d.dispose();
            removeAll();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: A hell of an answer

Answer (score 0):

below example code can be a good solution:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TableToImage
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final JTable table = getTable();
    JButton save = new JButton("save");
    save.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            saveToImage(table, table.getTableHeader());
        }
    });
    JPanel north = new JPanel();
    north.add(save);
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.getContentPane().add(north, "North");
    f.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(table));
    f.setSize(400,400);
    f.setLocation(200,200);
    f.setVisible(true);
}

private static JTable getTable()
{
    String[] headers = {
        "column 1", "column 2", "column 3", "column 4"
    };
    int rows = 50;
    int cols = 4;
    String[][] data = new String[rows][cols];
    for(int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
        for(int k = 0; k < cols; k++)
            data[j][k] = "item " + (j * cols + k + 1);
    return new JTable(data, headers);
}

private static void saveToImage(JTable table, JTableHeader header)
{
    int w = Math.max(table.getWidth(), header.getWidth());
    int h = table.getHeight() + header.getHeight();
    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g2 = bi.createGraphics();
    header.paint(g2);
    g2.translate(0, header.getHeight());
    table.paint(g2);
    g2.dispose();
    try
    {
 String userHomeFolder = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop";
        ImageIO.write(bi, "png", new File(userHomeFolder,"tableImage.png"));
    }
    catch(IOException ioe)
    {
        System.out.println("write: " + ioe.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```